# Dotnet core 2 consuming high CPU

Tags: c#, .net-core

I just created a new project using `dotnet new angular`(using MAC) and when I run using `dotnet run` for the first time it seems fine. Now I exited the process with `control + c` made some changes and again run. This time after few seconds the CPU consumption of dotnet core becomes very high close to 100%.

My observations are,

1. First time when I run `dotnet run` in Activity moniter i see multiple dotnet instances. When i exited the process in command prompt with `control + c` not all the process are getting killed.
2. Always there is one process stays and it is consuming CPU nearly 100%.

This happens often to me. Did anyone come across such issue or what might be wrong here? Please help me on this I couldn't do developement in dotnet core because of this.

I raised issue here [github link](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1553).

Comment: @mjwills I didn't add anything to the newly created project which the command `dotnet new angular`. Also this happens even for console projects and that source is there in the link I provided.

Comment: I think expecting people to go to another website, download an untrusted zip file, open it up and run it is quite a high bar. I'd suggest reading [mcve] again.

Comment: @mjwills Sorry for that. As I mentioned earlier I didn't change any line in the code which `dotnet new angular` generates. Still I need to post the code?

Comment: I killed the process and next time it's working fine with low CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an open issue on GitHub about this. See: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1553

The issue was moved to dotnet/roslyn. For the open issue see: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24137

Came across this topic when I was googling this issue myself.